# Is there any c++ static analysis tool to detect potential bug with vector

Tags: c++, vector, static-analysis

See the following code from [rust example](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/intro.html#ownership). Is there any static analysis tool to detect this problem?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    v.push_back("Hello");

    std::string& x = v[0];

    v.push_back("world");

    std::cout << x;
}
```

Comment: Try valgrind and address sanitizer (asan).

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan The question was about _static_ analysis tool.

Comment: @Mikhail sorry, I missed the "static" part there.

Answer (score 1):

The open-source program "cppcheck", fundamentally, has the ability to detect such errors. According to its [description](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/cppcheck/), it can detect, among other things:

> [...]
>
> - for vectors: using iterator/pointer after push_back has been used
>
> [...]

Unfortunately, the version I tested (1.63) does not detect the error in your code snippet. However, changing from reference to iterator creates a situation that it apparently can detect:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    v.push_back("Hello");

    std::string& x = v[0];
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = v.begin();

    v.push_back("world");

    std::cout << *it;
}
```

Storing this in `test.cpp` and running cppcheck:

```
cppcheck --std=c++03 ./test.cpp
```

I get the output below:

```
Checking test.cpp...
[test.cpp:15]: (error) After push_back(), the iterator 'it' may be invalid.
```

I suppose that's pretty close to what you are looking for.

Comment: if the `v.push_back("world");` is called in function, can it still be detected? Like: `HelpMePushBack(v)` and pass `v` as a reference.

Comment: @MarsonMao To the extent that the connection between the original vector and the reference or pointer to vector passed to the function can be traced, it is theoretically possible. cppcheck 1.63 does not do it, however (I just checked).

Comment: @jogojapan Thanks! But it's a pity our code base does not comply with --std=c++03 :(

Comment: @Patrick What do you mean? What does it comply with then? cppcheck offers various settings for `--std` -- I chose C++03 only because it is probably the most common.